# What are the potential pitfalls with the following code

Tags: c++, c

Consider a simple function to divide two floats,

```
float floatDiv(float x, float y)
{
    float z;
    z = x/y;
    return z;
}
```

All I can think of is when `y==0` it has undefined behavior. Any others?

Comment: The function looks very synthetic. It doesn't generally make sense to create a function for a simple arithmetic operation and no context is given in the question, that's IMO the most obvious pitfall.

Comment: You could also underflow.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior 1.0/0 might be infinite or another implementation  defined value

Comment: I have been told that `z=x/y' has potential pitfalls other than divide by 0 and I have to think it mathematically with visualization to see it. I did not write the method and I know it looks silly, but I am just asking to get any non-obvious answer.

Comment: Maybe division by a tiny number leading to an overflow (@NathanOliver)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Yes there is (in C++ at least). "If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @MikeSeymour You should distinguish undefined and implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @DieterLücking: I've no idea what you mean by that; I am distinguishing between them. Dividing by zero gives undefined behaviour, not implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: A pitfall may be that the `float` or `double` type may not have enough precision (bits) to support the accuracy you need.

Comment: **Very important read:** *(if you haven't done so already)* [What every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3):

Overflow and underflow are two pitfalls, where the true result of a division cannot be held in the data type. This example shows both. In the second case of underflow, the value is too small to be represented and becomes `0.0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
    float large, small;
    large = FLT_MAX / FLT_MIN;
    printf ("%f\n", (double)large);

    small = FLT_MIN / FLT_MAX;
    if (small == 0.0f) printf("Zero\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
1.#INF00
Zero
```

One of these could happen as an intermediate step in a calculation, so might not be obvious from the range of the expected result. One practical example of that is when computing the sum of an exponential series with alternate `+` and `-` terms, such as the series for `sin(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

A pitfall with using floating point is the accuracy, since the set of values that can be represented exactly is very small compared to the values that are not represented exactly.

Given:
  `z = x / y;`
The expression:
  `z * y`
may not be equal to `x` and depends on the precision capabilities of the floating point representation.